# Getting 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extra_dejson' error

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I configured my apache airflow. When I ran it from Apache UI, getting below error in logs. I searched a lot to figure out but no luck.

Error:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extra_dejson'

Answer (score 0):

This question would be much easier to support if you could include more of the trace back or error message.

Essentially, you are getting a Python runtime error, where a connection object is expected and the consuming code requires an `.extra_dejson` attribute set. This could happen at any point where the instance of code creating a connection instance produces an empty response, potentially from failure but likely from misconfiguration. And could happen in many places. More detail would help point to where you could make a change.